# paths for nested resource in rails not showing up in a restful fashion

Tags: rest, ruby-on-rails-4.2, nested-resources

I am using Rails 4.2.4. I want to create an endpoint for creating a nested resource called analysis_requests. I am using rails doc on nested resources as a starting point: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

routes.rb file

```
resource :companies do
    resource :analysis_requests
end
```

My Company model looks like this :

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :analysis_requests
end
```

When i generate the routes using rake routes, these are the routes i see.

```
companies_analysis_requests_path    POST    /companies/analysis_requests(.:format)  analysis_requests#create
```

edit_companies_analysis_requests_path   GET /companies/analysis_requests/edit(.:format) analysis_requests#edit

Why am i not able to see RESTful routes ? 
for example: should i not see

```
    POST    /companies/:company_id/analysis_requests(.:format)
```

analysis_requests#create

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, there was a typo in routes.rb file. specifying resources instead of 'resource' results in expected routes.

```
resources :companies do
    resources :analysis_requests
end
```